# How do i find the pixel value of the bottom of an element (div)

Tags: jquery

how can i find the pixel value of the bottom of an element. eg. the `#posts` div. i want to create a infinite scroller. and this is so that i can detect if the user has reached near/at the bottom of the #posts and i want to load new posts if so.

update:

i guess 1 option is to use

```
$("#header").height() + $("#posts").height()
```

but i want to make the code generic. so maybe i can convert this functionality into a plugin. the code above will not have taken into consideration, padding, margins, any elements above `#posts` etc.

Comment: This is a BAD IDEA, there is no way to produce a properly functioning infinity scroller that works on all platforms or doesn't flash like crazy on a tablet, etc.

Comment: hmm, why will it flash on a tablet? hmm i was thinking an infinite scroller will improve usability and will prevent users from having to click on the nav. something which they may not do or find it troublesome

Comment: You have race conditions, so for instance when you've reached the bottom (whilst holding on to the scrollbar) its to load new content to display... Depending on whether the OS has adjusted the scrollbar or the tablet drivers has dispatched a new event (like a slight movement) it will work, or it will drop you off somewhere unpredictable on the page. The comments section on jQuery drives me crazy as a WACOM user (on Mac and Windows XP/7). Even Nick Craver's example doesn't work - the mouseup event never triggers and suddenly the scrollbar is following the mouse.

Comment: @Metalshark - None the less, it's a useful question, though the OP may not be comfortable leaving tablets out, sometimes you can.  For example if I'm writing an *internal* website I know my audience exactly.  Also, who's to say you can't just not execute this for tablet users? :) 

The lack of scroll handling in a tablet isn't JavaScript/jQuery's fault IMO, this is a browser issue that needs fixing on the mobile side.  My example doesn't work with `mouseup` because it's an alert, a special case...the real code doing the loading won't have this.

Comment: Admittedly this is an edge case, but I've been a WACOM user for 10+ years - it does not report itself as anything other than a mouse - but exposes many GUI race conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var div = $('#posts');
var bottom = div.offset().top + div.height();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you had a `<div>` inside of `#posts` with the actual content, you'd do something like this:

```
$("#posts").scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() == ($("#posts_content").outerHeight() - $(this).height())) {
    alert("Reached Bottom!");
  }
});​
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MknA2/).  Upon a [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event, we're checking [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) of the `#pages` div to see how far it's scrolled down.  If that's equal to the inner-div's [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) minus the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) of `#pages` (because [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) gives the *top* position), then we throw an alert.

You can of course do whatever loading you need here, if you want it to load *before* the very bottom, just change the `==` to `>=` and slap a `-40` or something on the right side to load 40 pixels from the bottom.  [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/MknA2/1/):

```
$("#posts").scroll(function() {
  if($(this).scrollTop() >= ($("#posts_content").outerHeight() - $(this).height() - 40)) {
    alert("Reached Bottom!");
  }
});​
```

Comment: i think i need some time digesting this :) i think i am kind of a noob here. the 1st answer by sje397 seems to work fine. and is simple to understand. seems to work well enough for my case at the moment

Comment: @jiewmeng - This is more of a full solution, I misunderstood though, if you want to detect if the *page* has been scrolled (not `#posts` being a scroll window), it'd look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MknA2/2/

Comment: i wonder if that will work any differently from what i am currently using http://jsfiddle.net/MknA2/5/ i guess yours is shorted but i was just curious